# Debugging using Metal shader function

Tags: swift, debugging, swiftui, shader, metal

I use shader functions as modifier params for SwiftUI Views

Is there a way to debug shader function in Xcode, to print values or set up debugging points?

```
[[ stitchable ]] float2 someFunc(float2 position) {
    return position;
}
```

Comment: There is no way to debug these currently, I think.